# MPMoviePlayerViewController not playing the video mp4

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52719649/69090d547c8d47dd27b6d271649c59ae.mp4

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleVideo.mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
self.controller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.controller.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.controller];
[self.controller.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: In question you have asked for mp4 but in code you have written m4v, Is that the issue?

Comment: its mistakenly get added its mp4 actually

Comment: So you are setting that value dynamically, Right?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: just black screen and video wont play. Actually other videos plays but this video not able to play. Even though I add it in bundle and try to play.

Comment: Then there might be issue with recoding that video..

Answer (score 1):

you need to recompress the video as the current compression is incorrect:

- **<strike>H.264 Main Profile Level 4.0 video</strike>**

---

here is a guidance form Apple:

> - **H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0 video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps.** (The Baseline profile does not support B frames.)
> - **MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple Profile)**

the audio might need to be changed according to:

> (...) this class supports AAC-LC audio at up to 48 kHz, and MP3 (MPEG-1 Audio Layer 3) up to 48 kHz, stereo audio.

for `MPMoviePlayerController` ([Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html) in Apple's Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerViewController` instead. Follow this simple guide in order to play videos natively in your app:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_8_Video_Playback_using_AVPlayer_and_AVPlayerViewController

Comment: Does AVPlayerViewController supports the AMR Narrowband codec?

Comment: @prashant Try it and find out. This may be of use too - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21986105/4657588

Comment: @prashant, I don't think so, that audio is supported.

Comment: @holex: yes tried with AVplayer also its not working. audio codec is not supported.