# How to play MPEG-DASH with AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I was wondering what could be approach for AVPlayer to stream DASH (Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP). I saw this [AVFoundation (AVPlayer) supported formats? No .vob or .mpg containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879981/avfoundation-avplayer-supported-formats-no-vob-or-mpg-containers) but it looks AVFoundation has no support for DASH.

> This is the sample link
>   https://d28ny1s9kzd6a.cloudfront.net/shark+video/shark.mpd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into the following Github project or simply use it licence is MIT

https://github.com/Viblast/ios-player-sdk

Comment: Thanks, finally it can play. But the video player features are limited. Thumbs up.

Comment: can you use this library with Swift?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn’t open source, just a precompiled binary for iOS. I want to use this on macOS and tvOS…