# streaming videos from google drive in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

im trying to stream videos from google drive but its not working

this is my code

```
func playVideo () {


    let url = NSURL(string: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9XuPgWwSkzrdHN5WWUydjJScDg/preview")!

    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    playerViewController.player = player

    self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player?.play()
    }

}
```

i get this when i start the function [image here](http://i.imgur.com/hazFQx0.png)

Comment: i found  a way on android but i dont know how to do it on ios http://stackoverflow.com/a/33625394/5605581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem by Decodeing the html from the link and take the steam link from it

you can see the code here : https://github.com/DevZaid/GDSLink

Comment: This solution is not working, Is there any other update for this?

Answer (score 0):

your link is to flash video, not to some video supported by AVPlayer.

Comment: and how i can get the video supported by AVPlayer ??

Comment: from your link? there is no way. To see what kind of video is supported by AVPlayer I suggest you to check apple documentation or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879981/avfoundation-avplayer-supported-formats-no-vob-or-mpg-containers