# HTTP Live streaming is not readable and not work in AVPlayer Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, iptv

I am just trying to play network stream in AVPlayer. I can't share the link but this is some informations about :

[image: stream infos]

And the code :

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: inUrl)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let playern = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

print("playable = \(asset.isReadable)") // => false

playern.allowsExternalPlayback = true
playern.play()
```

Is there something that I'm missing ?

Comment: Do you know what's the video format you're trying to play?

Comment: Format is mpegts. Video is h264 compressed. And http mime-type is mp2ts

Comment: I'm not sure if that format is compatible with `AVPlayer` out of the box. You might need a custom parser for it. According to the `AVURLAsset` documentation, the audioVisualTypes method doesn't return the one you're trying to play.

Comment: I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879981/avfoundation-avplayer-supported-formats-no-vob-or-mpg-containers , but I just try on iphone and I think like you that’s It’s note supported. 
I don’t want to use third part lib to success but I’m confused. If you have a hint ?

Comment: The step I’m missing is to fragment my mpeg-ts to HLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step I’m missing was to fragment my mpeg-ts to HLS because `AVPlayer` can't read my stream.

I finally chose to use **MobileVLCKit** (https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit) which provide `VLCMediaPlayer` natively play my network stream.