# [iOS][AvFoundation] Need to get the similar classes like MediaCodec in android

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, tvos

is there any class in iOS which returns encoder/ decoder capabilities just like Android MediaCodec/ MediaCodecList.(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec)

I need to get the fps/profile/level and width /height supported on each profile of h264 and hevc codec.

I have found it related to AvCaptureSession, but this may not be correct since we need to support AvPlayer only (and camera is not in the part of the flow.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation has very limited supported formats. Refer to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879981/avfoundation-avplayer-supported-formats-no-vob-or-mpg-containers)

So If somebody wants to query for the codec info, I recommend him/she use ffmpeg. To be specific, it's [ffmpeg-kit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit). Check [here](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/apple) for all API documentation.

I wrote you a sample about how to use it in iOS and query for codec info(or anything you want). Please check it out:
[showcase](https://github.com/kasimok/ffmpegkit-showcase)

```
    let mediaInfoSession = FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation(kSampleFilePath)
    let mediaInfo = mediaInfoSession?.getMediaInformation()
    let props = mediaInfo?.getAllProperties()
    let duration = mediaInfo?.getDuration()
    let bitRate = mediaInfo?.getBitrate()
    ...
```

[image]

Feel free to contact me.