# How to play mkv file using flutter video_player?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

I am trying to play an .mkv file using. flutters video_player and a api link. When i try to play a mp4 video it works, but when i play a mkv video it gives me the error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Cannot Open, null, null)

This is my current code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayerTestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoUrl;
  final String username;
  final String password;
  final String streamId;
  final String containerExtension;

  const VideoPlayerTestScreen({
    required this.videoUrl,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
    required this.streamId,
    required this.containerExtension,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerTestScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerTestScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerTestScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerTestScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Final Video URL: ${widget.videoUrl}'); // Print the final URL
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(widget.videoUrl),
      httpHeaders: {}, 
    )..initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Video Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _controller.value.isInitialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              )
            : Container(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _controller.value.isPlaying
                ? _controller.pause()
                : _controller.play();
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

When i enter the api url of the mp4 file in my browser, it shows the video directly on a page. But with the .mkv file it downloads the file to my pc instead of showing it on the page.

I tried searching on stackoverflow, google search and github. Could not find any helping solutions yet.

Answer (score 0):

.mkv is just a container format, support is going to also depend on the codecs used inside it - the file is .mkv but the video could be encoded as H.264, H.265, VP9, etc

The video_player package has links to the [supported formats](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player#supported-formats).

> Supported Formats
>
> On iOS and macOS, the backing player is AVPlayer. The supported formats vary depending on the version of iOS, AVURLAsset class has
> audiovisualTypes that you can query for supported av formats.
>
> On Android, the backing player is ExoPlayer, please refer [here](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html) for list of supported formats.
>
> On Web, available formats depend on your users' browsers (vendor and version). Check [package:video_player_web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web) for more specific
> information.

There is another answer specifically with the [supported iOS formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986105/20997501).

The [supported formats for ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/media/media3/exoplayer/supported-formats) do include Matroska (mkv) so it should work on Android.

[Supported formats for the web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web#supported-formats) is going to depend on what browser you are using.

If the video is not already encoded as H.264 I would re-encode as that so it has the most compatibility across browsers.